# Displaying private HTML file from AWS S3

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I'm currently hosting a static website on AWS S3. I have parts of the website that I only want AWS Cognito authenticated users to access. These parts of the S3 bucket are restricted to certain roles. As I understand it, once a Cognito user has received their temporary AWS credentials, I need to use the S3 sdk to load the restricted object (index.html) from S3 and display it in the webpage. Is this the correct approach, and once I have the object back from S3, how do I go about loading it into the webpage? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "parts of the website"? Do you mean elements like images, or do you mean HTML pages? For example, what do you mean by "load the restricted object (index.html) from S3 and display it in the webpage"? Do you intend to have any Amazon EC2 instances or use any AWS Lambda functions to handle your application & security logic?

Comment: So all of my different index.html files are hosted on AWS S3. I want to change the page to a different index.html when a user clicks on a certain link in my website. When the click this link, however, their credentials are verified and then I need to ensure that they have the proper permissions to access that webpage. Once the permissions are verified, I want to load the new index.html to be the current page. I hope that clears it up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need **application logic** that runs in the back-end to control your security and to store/retrieve data. While much of this can be done from the browser, it is open to hacking. Therefore, you need your access control logic in the back-end.

**Option 1: API Gateway and Lambda functions**

You can have a static web page served out of Amazon S3, which makes API calls to Lambda functions via API Gateway. This is known as the **serverless model**.

Here's a sample diagram from the [Serverless Code website](https://serverlesscode.com/post/david-guetta-online-recording-with-lambda/):

[image: Serverless architecture]

Basically, Lambda functions receive the request, determine whether the user is authorised, determines what they would receive back (eg a pre-signed URL to a different page) and sends it back to the web page. The benefit of this design is that it does not require any servers.

**Option 2: Amazon EC2 servers**

Alternatively, you can run Amazon EC2 instances fronted by an Elastic Load Balancer. This is traditional application design allowing you to use many different frameworks. However, there is an on-going cost for the servers even when nobody is using your application.